# Push state without retriggering component load

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Lets say I have only one component which fetches some data on being mounted. 
I want to be able to change the url (pushState) once the component fetches that data however I dont want to change anything on the page or re-render the component.

Let's say I have a route '/' and it loads a  which fetches searched contents on load. Once the data is fetched, I want to be able to update the url to say /searchterm

I am looking to do something similar to 
window.history.pushState(null, null, '/searchterm') where the url is updated but nothing on the page changes.

Tried using  with state and using this.props.history.push

Comment: Can you add the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the route in your state, and then [memoize](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate) the component with a function that returns true if the route changes, which will prevent an update.  If you're still using class components, you can implement similar functionality using [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate)